# Send two of the same param to ui-sref

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ui-sref

How would I pass two of the same parameters to ui-sref?

```
productSearch({'d': 53, 'b': 20, 'b': 19, 's': 6, 'b': 19})
```

the 'b' param just uses the latter value of 19.

How would I include two b values to go to this url:

http://example.com/search?d=53&s=6&b=20&b=19

Thank you very much!

Comment: to make it valid keys must be unique, if you want unique values use an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of syntax. All languages I know which implement hash, or inline object notation don't support duplicate keys. It would not event make sense to do it. How are gonna access the params later? `params.b` and.... `params.b`.

It wouldn't make sense at the url level either. Query parsing programs will most likely take the value of the last `b`. I think this is standard behaviour.

Use an array instead (`productSearch({ b: [1,2,3] })`).

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to rename them to `b1` and `b2` for example? I think in every language and in every framework/library similar approach will cause naming inconsistense. You are configuring your params, so call them differently and configure your state with them